# How to rewrite this JQuery plugin into AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a code here and i want to make it usable for AngularJS. this's the original plugin [PAPER COLLAPSE](http://bbo-code.com/components/paper-collapse) i want to use it in a AngularJS project so i'll be able to Do `ng-repeat`

here's the jQuery Plugin's code

```
(function() {
  (function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.paperCollapse = function(options) {
      var settings;
      settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.paperCollapse.defaults, options);
      $(this).find('.collapse-card__heading').add(settings.closeHandler).click(function() {
        if ($(this).closest('.collapse-card').hasClass('active')) {
          settings.onHide.call(this);
          $(this).closest('.collapse-card').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('.collapse-card').find('.collapse-card__body').slideUp(settings.animationDuration, settings.onHideComplete);
        } else {
          settings.onShow.call(this);
          $(this).closest('.collapse-card').addClass('active');
          $(this).closest('.collapse-card').find('.collapse-card__body').slideDown(settings.animationDuration, settings.onShowComplete);
        }
      });
      return this;
    };
    $.fn.paperCollapse.defaults = {
      animationDuration: 400,
      easing: 'swing',
      closeHandler: '.collapse-card__close_handler',
      onShow: function() {},
      onHide: function() {},
      onShowComplete: function() {},
      onHideComplete: function() {}
    };
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a directive and your code in the link function

Comment: @Raulucco can you please give me example !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy, see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQKVKi?p=preview). You'll probably want to tune the css abit.

There's no solid way to do a css only slideUp/slideDown, but if you don't mind including jquery you can always add a watch on `card.$active` and do the slide via jquery.